# Get exported metadata without using ImportAttribute or ImportManyAttribute in MEF?

Tags: c#, prism, mef

I believe that the `ImportAttribute` or `ImportManyAttribute` behind the scenes should use some core methods of MEF to get the exported metadata paired with the actual instance of the exported type. Using those attributes works fine with the following setup:

```
//the metadata interface
public interface IMetadata {
    string Name {get;}
}
//the custom ExportAttribute
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
[MetadataAttribute]
public class CustomExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IMetadata {

    public string Name {get;set;}
}
//the class which need to be exported (both value and metadata)
[CustomExport(Name = "someName")]
public class A {
}
//the class which imports the exported value and metadata
[Export]
public class B {
    [Import]
    public Lazy<A, IMetadata> AData {get;set;}
}
```

Now when getting the exported value of B, I can browse the `AData` with correctly exported instance of `A` and its associated metadata via `IMetadata` interface, like this:

```
var ac = new AggregateCatalog();
ac.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("."));
var c = new CompositionContainer(ac);
var b = c.GetExportedValue<B>();
var data = b.AData.Value;//some instance of A here
var mdata = b.AData.Metadata;//some metadata of A here
```

However I don't want to use the class `B` in this case, how could I obtain the exported pair of instance of A and its metadata? Because not using any class (like `B`), the attribute `ImportAttribute` is also not used in this case.
Here is what I've tried:

```
var ac = new AggregateCatalog();
ac.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("."));
var c = new CompositionContainer(ac);
var a = c.GetExportedValue<Lazy<A,IMetadata>>();
```

The last line above throws the exception `ImportCardinalityMismatchException`, like this:

> No exports were found that match the constraint: ContractName System.Lazy(Test.A,Test.IMetadata)  RequiredTypeIdentity System.Lazy(Test.A,Test.IMetadata)

I believe that there must be some way to get the exported value (pair of type instance and its metadata) directly without using a dummy class in which the `ImportAttribute` is used to store  the exported value in some property of that class.

I'm still getting started with MEF and Prism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way indeed! No need for the export to be imported in another class. Just use **GetExport< T, TMetadataView >** method. Based on your code I made it work only by adding:

```
var wow = c.GetExport<A, IMetadata>();
```

This returns just what you want, a **Lazy < T, TMetadataView >**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well it's a bit hidden, it really helps, thanks. The issue I cared about has been far away since I'm now involved in other problems, I have not tested this yet but I believe it should work!